# What is the mathematical term for Haskell Num typeclass?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, computer-science, programming

The definition of Haskell `Num` typeclass:

```
class  Num a  where
    {-# MINIMAL (+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-)) #-}

    (+), (-), (*)       :: a -> a -> a
    -- | Unary negation.
    negate              :: a -> a
    -- | Absolute value.
    abs                 :: a -> a
    -- | Sign of a number.
    -- The functions 'abs' and 'signum' should satisfy the law:
    --
    -- > abs x * signum x == x
    --
    -- For real numbers, the 'signum' is either @-1@ (negative), @0@ (zero)
    -- or @1@ (positive).
    signum              :: a -> a
    -- | Conversion from an 'Integer'.
    -- An integer literal represents the application of the function
    -- 'fromInteger' to the appropriate value of type 'Integer',
    -- so such literals have type @('Num' a) => a@.
    fromInteger         :: Integer -> a

    {-# INLINE (-) #-}
    {-# INLINE negate #-}
    x - y               = x + negate y
    negate x            = 0 - x
```

Though Haskell standard defines no laws, there are some conventions.

The presence of $(+)$, $(-)$, $\text{negate}$, and $(×)$ suggests this is a ring. Let's denote the ring $R$.

The $\text{fromInteger}$ is a homomorphism from $ℤ$ to $R$. Also, it must satisfy that $\text{fromInteger }0 = 0$ and $\text{fromInteger }1 = 1$. So the ring must have unity.

$\text{abs}$ is mathematically troublesome to define. If this denoted norm, it would have type $\text{abs}: R \rightarrow ℝ$. But actually, it has type $\text{abs}: R \rightarrow R$! So let's define norm $R \rightarrow ℝ$ and a homomorphism $ℝ \rightarrow R$, and compose them.

$\text{signum}$ is defined as $\text{signum }x = x ÷ \text{abs }x$, if $x ≠ 0$ and the ring is a division ring.

Is there a mathematical term that summerizes all these ideas?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell

Comment: It's a base type for numeric types (integers, rationals, doubles). I don't think there is more to it mathematically.

Comment: If we take the conventions seriously, then you're exactly right that it characterises rings. The fromInteger doesn't give us anything more interesting, since https://yutsumura.com/there-is-exactly-one-ring-homomorphism-from-the-ring-of-integers-to-any-ring/. The absolute value thing is a bit curious, since I don't think this makes much sense at all when we have torsion, potentially leaving us with only free modules over $\mathbb{Z}$ (somebody else might have a more sensible notion of $abs$ to apply to other spaces).

Comment: "Abomination." :-)

Comment: Likely an [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) is intended, but without any axioms one cannot be sure.

Comment: Perhaps a "normed ring" or something? The default Haskell numeric types were only designed to cover integers, rationals, real numbers and complex numbers (as IEEE floating-point numbers). The Num typeclass could be seen as an ad-hoc bunch of operations which make sense on all those kinds of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a conversation in [Haskell Libraries Mailing List,](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2020-January/thread.html) I can answer this question myself.

There are at least 3 ways to define `abs`:

## Absolute Value

For an ordered ring, values can be classified to positive values, zero, or negative value. As a consequence, I can give a top-level function for absolute value:

```
realAbs :: Real a => a -> a
realAbs x = if 0 <= x
    then x
    else negate x
```

Then I can let `abs = realAbs`.

## Norm

If norm of every element is also an element, `abs` can be defined as the norm.

## Associates of Action of Group of Units

Let $R$ be the ring and take group of units $U(R)$. Then $U(R)$ acts on $R$, then I can pick representives from each associates. For example, Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}^2$ have group of units $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$, and thus `abs` of Gaussian integers can be defined like:

```
instance Integral a => Num (Complex a) where
    abs 0 = 0
    abs (x :+ y) = if 0 < x && 0 <= y
        then x :+ y
        else if x <= 0 && 0 < y
            then y :+ negate x
            else if x < 0 && y <= 0
                then negate x :+ negate y
                else negate y :+ x
```